# Is it possible for ejs and vue.js to co-exist in the nodejs + express environment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js, ejs

I started off with a website by using NodejS + Express + ejs (using JQuery based Datatables etc) and it worked very well thus far. But we are planning to move to Vue.js UI framework in the company. So one way is ro migrate all ejs work to Vue.JS, but that would be very involved. So was wondering if we could have them co-exist so that the new functionality we introduce would be in Vue.JS. This way we could serve both ejs and vue.js using the same node server.

Comment: yes they can, you wouldn't need to change much except adding an endpoint to serve the dist files, perhaps served though static middleware (1 additional line), vue js on its own is not server side rendered so your going from one paradigm to another, so if your data is primarily rendered serve-side in your ejs template, the major work would be in making all the api endpoints, though again that wouldn't be much work you would just add some middleware or go through each controller and tweak .render lines

Comment: Sounds good. Will you be able to put some sample code or point me to an external source?